# KDE Theme broken after 13.10 → 14.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, themes, kde, 14.04

I just did the upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 and the default KDE theme not looks like no theme at all:

[image: KDE theme has no theme]

I usually use KDE with Awesome WM as the window manager, but even without Awesome WM, this looks bad.

As far as I can tell, all oxygen packages that I could possibly need are installed:

```
i   gtk2-engines-oxygen                                          - Widget-Thema Oxygen für GTK+-Anwendungen                               
p   gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386                                     - Widget-Thema Oxygen für GTK+-Anwendungen                               
i   gtk3-engines-oxygen                                          - Oxygen widget theme for GTK3-based applications                        
p   gtk3-engines-oxygen:i386                                     - Oxygen widget theme for GTK3-based applications                        
i   kde-style-oxygen                                             - Oxygen widget style                                                    
p   kde-style-oxygen:i386                                        - Oxygen widget style                                                    
i   libreoffice-style-oxygen                                     - office productivity suite -- Oxygen symbol style                       
i   oxygen-cursor-theme                                          - Oxygen mouse cursor theme                                              
p   oxygen-cursor-theme-extra                                    - Oxygen mouse cursor theme - extra colors                               
i   oxygen-icon-theme                                            - Oxygen icon theme                                                      
p   oxygen-icon-theme-complete                                   - Oxygen icon theme - transitional package                               
p   oxygen-molecule                                              - GTK+ theme to match the Oxygen widget style                            
i   ttf-oxygen-font-family                                       - Oxygen font family                                                     
p   ttf-oxygen-font-family:i386                                  - Oxygen font family
```

In the systemsettings, it does not show oxygen:

[image: KDE settings manager has missing theme]

How can I get the Oxygen theme back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution [in the Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=137257):

> It turned out it is indeed a configuration error. To anyone having this issue: delete `~/.config/Trolltech.conf`

That fixed it.

Comment: I didn't think that this would have applied to 15.04 with plasma 5, but I had the same problem (ugly widget style or window controls) and couldn't set the "breeze" ones. This solved it perfectly!