# Theme and icons look old after upgrade to 14.04 - AMD GPU issues?

Tags: unity, ati, themes, icons, 14.04

Yesterday I upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 and I ran into a few problems. Interestingly I upgraded two computers (one of which has identical hardware) before this one and had no problems.

When I booted up after the upgrade the screen was flickering, artifacts were everywhere, the 'theme' and icons looked like they came from a old version of Gnome and the background appeared only on half of one of my monitors (the rest was black and I couldn't even move my mouse on the black area). I have an AMD R9 280x so immediately my thought was that I should purge and reinstall the proprietary drivers. I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-dev
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -rf /etc/ati
```

After a restart the flickering issue was gone and my two monitors appeared to behave mostly ok (only problem is that the CCW I put on my 2nd monitor doesn't survive a restart), but the icons, buttons and theme remain looking like they came out an old version of Gnome. Also, the menu bar appears twice in every window: once in the title bar and once well as below in it's own barHere are some photos to show what I mean (sorry about the quality; I had to take them with my phone because the 'Print Scrn' button has also stopped working after the upgrade):

[image: Old looking theme and icons]

[image: Old looking theme on Download window]

[image: Double menu bar]

How can I fix this and get my 14.04 looking as beautiful as it was designed to look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone with Kubuntu had a similar problem and it turns out the solution works with Unity also:

[KDE Theme broken after 13.10 → 14.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449731/kde-theme-broken-after-13-10-14-04-upgrade)

Original source from the Arch forums:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=137257

Long story short I just removed ~/.config/Trolltech.conf and restarted. Now my desktop is looking great!

Comment: Since you answered your own question, you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: No need to do a full restart; just [restart X Window Server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1220/how-to-restart-x-window-server-from-command-line).